# Historical or literary examples of misguided or botched attempts to help that end up causing harm

Tags: expressions, idioms, phrase-requests, expression-choice, metaphors

I'm looking for examples from history, folklore, literature, movies, or pop culture, of situations in which a person or group attempted to do something helpful but, *due to their own poor judgment, incompetence, or naïveté*, ended up causing harm to the people, project, or cause that they intended to help. The main idea is that the erstwhile helpers are to blame for the damage they caused, to such an extent that the fact that they meant well is no excuse.

I'm asking this for the purpose of having a vivid, emotive example to use in a piece of persuasive writing, in which merely stating the fact that harm was caused is not sufficiently impactful.

Comment: In this vein: “God save us from people who mean well.” 
― Vikram Seth, A Suitable Boy //

“Most of the evil in this world is done by people with good intentions.” 
― T.S. Eliot

Comment: For reference, another previous question that bears some resemblance to this one is [Word to describe a situation where one wants to do good things but ends up with something bad](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215448/word-to-describe-a-situation-where-one-wants-to-do-good-things-but-ends-up-with).

Comment: @ermanen – Good find there, but rather than a literal description or an aphorism, I'm looking for an idiom, a metaphor, or a recognizable situation from literature.

Comment: Snatching defeat from the jaws of victory.

Comment: @ermanen: I have rewritten this question so as to more clearly distinguish it from the previous question you cite as a duplicate. Please reconsider your duplication assessment.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I have rewritten this question. Please reconsider your duplication assessment.

Comment: @drew: I have rewritten this question. Please reconsider your duplication assessment.

Comment: @medica: I have rewritten this question. Please reconsider your duplication assessment.

Comment: @phenry: I have rewritten this question. Please reconsider your duplication assessment.

Comment: It's now not a duplicate. Now, it's not a question about the English language.

Comment: @edwin: Well of course it is. I'm looking for a way to express a certain meaning, and English is most definitely the language I'm using. Are we limited here only to narrow questions of grammar and vocabulary?

Comment: The ones who bother to observe the aims of the website are. Though _We_ don't usually find the field narrow. We also usually conform to posters' ways of writing their user names. Perhaps the Writers S E or History S E are more appropriate websites for your new question. I believe they use English too.

Comment: @edwin: OK, OK. Isn't there some way to rewrite the question so that it's clear that the answers provided to the previous question of which you allege this is a duplicate do not adequately address the specifics of what I'm seeking? In particular, I don't think the answers to the previous question (or most of the answers thus far to this one, for that matter) specifically indicate that the failure of the good intentions was attributable to "poor judgment, incompetence, or naïveté" on the part of the helpers. It can be any kind of expression, as long as that condition is satisfied.

Comment: I'd be happy to use the suggestions of Des Adams or FF. 'Their bumbling attempts to help' is fairly common. "Deliver us from well meaning fools" is a prayer or pseudo-prayer used in this connection.

Answer (score 12):

The quintessential exclamation from the person receiving this sort of "help" would be:

> With friends like these, who needs enemies?

It's also possible that you'd find that

> The cure is worse than the disease

In that accepting their assistance is worse than just living with your original situation.

You might also say that

> I can't afford any more help like this.

Probably the shortest charitable way to describe such assistance is to say that it was "well-intentioned" or "well-meant", as seen from this entry at [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well-meaning) for "well-meaning":

> : having or showing a desire to do something good but often producing bad results

Comment: To me "well-intentioned" does not necessarily imply the result was bad, it may also just have been an inconsequential or futile effort. Also I'm not sure it counts as an idiom, otherwise the OP would not have mentioned a similar phrase in his question.

Answer (score 8):

There's an English proverb that goes:

> The road to hell is paved with good intentions.

It's pretty broad in its scope of application, but it would certainly apply here.

There's another saying that might fit this situation:

> No good deed goes unpunished.

Comment: I was going to suggest the first phrase, but according to [at least one source](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/the-road-to-hell-is-paved-with-good-intentions.html) it's supposed to mean "there is no merit in good intentions unless they are acted on". Similarly, Wikipedia [gives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_road_to_hell_is_paved_with_good_intentions) "hell is full of good meanings, but heaven is full of good works" as an alternative form.

Comment: I'd also say the first phrase, except that it is not an idiom but a proverb. You can't really say "his good intentions paved the road to hell".

Comment: @jiggunjer - I wrote "There's an English proverb that goes:

The road to hell is paved with good intentions." I don't understand the problem you're having.

Answer (score 4):

There are several synonymous variants of a phrase that seems to suit your purpose:

- more hindrance than help
- more a hindrance than a help
- more of a hindrance than a help
- less help than hindrance
- less a help than a hindrance
- less of a help than a hindrance

Of these, the most common seems to be "more of a hindrance than a help", though I seem to recall that the "more of a" construction is chiefly American, so I imagine that British English speakers would probably prefer "more a hindrance than a help".

Answer (score 2):

A term from spy-craft and international politics is "blowback". E.g. you spend years training insurgents to fight your enemy, and then they turn around and attack you. If you're looking for a real-world example, the late and not lamented Osama bin Laden is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

**Too many cooks spoil the broth**
[Wiktionary](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/too_many_cooks_spoil_the_broth)
says

> If too many people participate in a task, they spoil everything

Perhaps the "helpers" all had good intentions but in the end, the result was disasterous.

Comment: When it comes to the future, you can never have too many cooks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question reminds me of these verses from *The Fool's Prayer* by Edward Rowland Sill:

```
"These clumsy feet, still in the mire,   
  Go crushing blossoms without end;  
These hard, well-meaning hands we thrust     
  Among the heart-strings of a friend.   

"The ill-timed truth we might have kept—     
  Who knows how sharp it pierced and stung?  
The word we had not sense to say—    
  Who knows how grandly it had rung?
```

I don't know how many people would get it if you made a reference to the poem or these verses.  Sill is one of my favorite poets, but the fact that I was recently able to buy a 120-year-old book of his poems in good condition for about US$10 suggests that he's perhaps not the most popular poet in the world...

In any case, I think **well-intentioned** is the best way to express this idea.  This is an example of [damning with faint praise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damning_with_faint_praise), as you wouldn't mention the merit of the intention if the attempt were actually helpful.

Comment: Thank you for providing a relevant literary citation! I agree it's obscure, but interesting nonetheless. =)

Answer (score 1):

I thought of some metaphors for good intentioned help that goes harmfully wrong.

Medical inspired:

- He amputated the wrong organ.
- He made a hole in its head to remove evil spirits.

Variants based on existing idioms/proverbs:

- He lent a barbed hand.
- He helped pave the road to hell.
- He accidentally led the bull into the china shop.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

***Thanks for nothing!***

> [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Thanks%20for%20nothing)
>
> A sarcastic expression of frustration or displeasure at someone/thing.
>
> More literal definition: I have no thanks for you because you aren't
>   doing what I want or did something I didn't want.
>
> [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/thanks-for-nothing)
>
> used to show you are annoyed when someone has done something you are
>   unhappy about or has failed to help you in some way:

[image]

---

***Beware of Trojans bearing gifts!***

A turn on the expression *[Beware of Greeks bearing gifts](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/beware-of-greeks-bearing-gifts.html)*:

> Meaning: Don't trust your enemies.
>
> Origin
>
> An allusion to the story of the wooden
>   horse of Troy, used by the Greeks to trick their way into the city. It
>   is recorded in Virgil's *Aeneid*, Book 2, 19 BC:
>
> *"Do not trust the horse, Trojans. Whatever it is, I fear the Greeks
>   even when they bring gifts."*
>
> Of course that English version is a translation. Another translation,
>   by John Dryden, has *"Trust not their presents, nor admit the horse."*
>
> The same thought was also recorded by Sophocles (496 - 406 BC), in
>   Ajax:
>
> *Nought from the Greeks towards me hath sped well. So now I find that
>   ancient proverb true, Foes' gifts are no gifts: profit bring they
>   none.*
>
> The Classics are no longer widely taught or read, so this phrase is
>   now little used, although it was resurrected in a sideways reference
>   during a 1990s copyright dispute. There was considerable discussion
>   then, in Internet chat rooms etc., regarding the company Compuserve,
>   which owned the copyright to the GIF image format, and their possible
>   intentions to restrict its use. Some people feared that they might be
>   taken to law by Compuserve if they received and viewed GIF images
>   without permission. The phrase "beware of geeks bearing gifs" was
>   coined to sum that up.

When your friends come to help but end up harming you, the "Trojan horse" is homemade, so *beware of Trojans bearing gifts* means:

**You can't trust your friends when they come to help.**

Comment: The animation and profanity are both uncalled for, and don't add value to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

***Sod's law*** is what it might be called in Britain.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "[Sod's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sod%27s_law)" is the UK equivalent of what Americans call "[Murphy's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law)": "If something can go wrong, it will." Thanks, but that's not really what I was going for.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I think there are subtle differences between Sod and Murphy.

Comment: Wiki says: *According to David J. Hand, emeritus professor of mathematics...Imperial College London, Sod's law is a more extreme version of Murphy's law. (The latter) says that anything that can go wrong, will go wrong (eventually), Sod's law requires that it always go wrong with the worst possible outcome.

Answer (score 0):

How about 'to do someone a disservice'? The Swedish language has the word 'björntjänst', literally 'bear service', meaning a disservice, but I don't know any such term in English with suitably quaint origins.

The idea perhaps being something like:

- A tree has a beehive in it
- A man falls asleep under the tree
- Honey drips onto the sleeping man
- A wandering bear licks the honey off the man but accidentally ends up eating him

Answer (score -1):

- "The Midas Touch" of King Midas who, e.g., turned his loved ones into gold statues after his wish was granted
- "Panglossian," e.g., panglossian efforts of the missionaries; from the character in Voltaire's *Candide*
- Don Quixote and quixotic

Answer (score -3):

*Going down with the ship*? Very tough question to be honest.

Comment: Please give a rationale for your answer.